# Spreadsheet API json not working on different systems

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have created a project for accessing data from google spreadsheet using API. I am using the JSON created using my email Id in my project. But when the same project is run on some other system, it cannot access the spreadsheet data. What could be the possible reason and how it can be fixed?

Comment: You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample#introduction). To use the new JSON feed, create a script element whose src value is `http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/key/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc` where `feed` is the type of feed, `key` is the key of the spreadsheet you want to retrieve, the `worksheet` is the positional or unique identifier of the worksheet, and `myFunc` is the name of your callback function that is passed the JSON object.

Comment: You can also follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a) on how to import JSON data into Google Spreadsheets.